# Google chart - legend

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I would like to change my legend, I must have remove pagging and put all tittles in one or two rows. And i would like to change icon.

It's look like this now

[image]

I would like something like this

[image]

I put scrollArrows: 'none' but it doesn't work.
This is my code in controller:

```
var optionsMobile = {
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
pointSize: 5,
series: {
    pointShape: 'circle'
},
chartArea: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '70%'
},
legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    pagingTextStyle: { color: '#666' },
    scrollArrows: 'none'
},
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
titleTextStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    height: "40px"
},
hAxis: {
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    }
},
vAxis: {
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white'
    }
},
};
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)...

> Set `legend.maxLines` to a number greater than one to add lines to your legend.
>   This option currently works only with `legend.position: 'top'`
>   *Note: The exact logic used to determine the actual number of lines rendered is still in flux.*

```
var options = {
  legend: {
    maxLines: 2,
    position: 'top'
  }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'NYCLS 2016 Boys', 'NYCLS 2016 Girls', 'NYCLS 2017 Boys', 'NYCLS 2017 Girls'],
    [1, 10, 15, 20, 25],
    [2, 12, 18, 24, 30],
    [3, 14, 21, 28, 35],
    [4, 16, 24, 32, 40]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      maxLines: 2,
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: 360
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```